# How to (re-)trigger an Azure function from Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-storage-explorer

I have an Azure Function triggered by blob: `BlobTrigger("input/{name}"`

From Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, is there an easy way to (re-)trigger this function other than downloading the file, deleting the blob and uploading the file?

Comment: You can trigger function when you change blob tier, blob renamed

Comment: In portal you can trigger when an event is created by using event grid https://i.imgur.com/wI9R6l8.png

Comment: You can trigger function to get SAS token for your container

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is using event hub trigger to azure function, I have reproduced in my environment and followed below steps:
Created an event subscription as below from Azure Blob storage:

[image]

So, whenever you do any of the events in azure storage explorer such as renamed, blob tier changed , etc this event grid subscription triggers the end point (i.e the azure function).

[image]

You can trigger function when you change blob tier, blob renamed,get SAS token for your container.